# Date format in windows server

Tags: asp.net, windows, datetime

I have reinstalled my windows server 2008 and I have many issues with the date format.

In old version, the date format was dd/MM/yyyy and in the new installation the default date format is MM/d/yyy and I´m getting the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." in my pages.

How could I change the date format for all system, otherwise I will need to modify the sites individually.

Comment: Change the date time setting on the server. Right click the clock in bottom right, and go from there?

Comment: I changed it into the Regional Settings in the Control Panel but when I parse the date using DateTime.Parse(Request["CheckIn"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") the result is MM/d/yyyy. Any idea?

Comment: @ErnestoRodriguez What do you mean "the result is MM/d/yyyy". **DateTime has no format!** When you convert it to a string, you can specify a format to use. When you parse a string, you can specify a format to use. But DateTime itself *has no format*. Provide your code for how you're getting the result.